# how to add a lightbox image to bxslider (try to using colorbox)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slider').bxSlider(
          {
            auto: true,
            autoControls: true,
            stopAutoOnClick: true,
            pager: false,
            pause: 2000
          });

      $(".slide1").click(function () { 

      $.colorbox({
        width:"900px", 
        height:"600px", 
        iframe:true, 
        href:"http://via.placeholder.com/300x300"
      });
      });
      

 
          
          
        $('.slide2').click(function() {
            $.colorbox({
    onOpen:function(){ 
                alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
       
                onLoad:function(){ 
                alert('onLoad: colorbox has start content'); },
       
                onComplete:function(){ 
                alert('onComplete: loaded content'); },
     
                onCleanup:function(){ 
                alert('onCleanup: begun the close process'); },
     
                onClosed:function(){ 
                alert('onClosed: completely closed'); }
            });
        });
    
  

          
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html lang="it-IT" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
     <meta name="theme-color" content="#1ebbf0"/>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.6.4/jquery.colorbox.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide1">
      <img  src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
     <div class="slide2">
      <img  src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to use two libraries, bxslider and color box, I want that when I click on a slide, colorbox open a modal tab with the image. Is that possible?
In this example when I click on slide1 I see a black modal windows, I think that there is a problem in my js code. Can someone help me to modify this code?

Answer (score 0):

My final code for this element is this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slider').bxSlider(
          {
              auto: true,
              autoHover: true,
              slideWidth: 900,
              slideHeight:450,
              adaptiveHeight: false,
              mode: 'horizontal',
              autoControls: true,
              stopAutoOnClick: true,
              pager: false,
              pause: 2000
          });

      $(".slide1").click(function () { 
        $.colorbox({
                    html:"<div class='image'><img src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'></div>",
                    maxWidth:'95%', 
                    maxHeight:'95%'});         
       
     });   
     
      $(".slide2").click(function () { 
        $.colorbox({
                    html:"<div class='image'><img src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'></div>",
                    maxWidth:'95%', 
                    maxHeight:'95%'});         
       
     });   

 
          
          

    
  

          
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html lang="it-IT" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
     <meta name="theme-color" content="#1ebbf0"/>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.6.4/jquery.colorbox.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide1">
      <img  src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
     <div class="slide2">
      <img  src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```